# I can I make this query run faster

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table that can be simplified to the below:

```
Create Table Data (
  DATAID bigint identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
  VALUE1 varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  VALUE2 varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_DATA PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (DATAID ASC)
)
```

Among others, this index exists:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX VALUEIDX ON dbo.DATA
(VALUE1 ASC) INCLUDE (VALUE2)
```

The table has about **9 million** rows with mostly sparse data in `VALUE1` and `VALUE2`.

The query `Select Count(*) from DATA` takes about 30 seconds. And the following query takes 1 minute and 30 seconds:

```
Select Count(*) from DATA Where VALUE1<>VALUE2
```

Is there any way I can make this faster? I basically need to find (and update) all rows where `VALUE1` is different from `VALUE2`. I considered adding a bit field called `ISDIFF` and update that via a Trigger whenever the value fields are updated is updated. But then I need to create an index on the bit field and select `WHERE ISDIFF=1`.

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: Using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Something is very wrong is `Select Count(*) from DATA` takes about 30 seconds. Edit: Try forcing an index rebuild.

Comment: Try to investigate DB/table by [DBCC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188796.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Rebuilding indexes did the trick. How often should indexes be re-built? We can we somehow automate this via SQL Agent ?